# socket.io sending parameter to php file

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have project that uses ajax long polling by using the technique of setTimeout but as I know this is not good to use if we are dealing with real time app and with js only.Someone told me that socket.io is suitable for this project.I am newbie in socket.io and I want to ask how can i deal with socket.io to send data parameter to my php server and grab the response from the php server same as what I did in my ajax call back. Is this possible ?

More help greatly appreciated thank you!.